# Gitignore file that exists in bare repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, gitignore

I'm trying to ignore a VisualGDB settings file that needs to be available in the repository for people to check out as a baseline. VisualGDB is a visual studio plugin, and I want programmers to be able to checkout a baseline VS project and be able to get up and running very quickly by just changing a few small settings.

The issue is I don't want the changes to be tracked once it has been checked out again. Each programmer is going to need this settings file as a template, but they will also need to make minor tweaks for their respective environments and I don't want there to be tons of versions of this file.

I created the repo with the baseline template settings, pushed it to the bare repo, cloned it to a new location, changed settings and added the settings files to gitignore, but it still tracks changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a file to git you can not ignore that.You can ignore jast untracked files.I think you should remove that file from git than ignore it and create a template folder with that file and add it to git as a template.

[Gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> NOTES
>   The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked.
>   To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use git rm --cached.

Comment: The problem is the location of this file matters, and this plugin doesn't allow changing the path to locate the settings (because the settings file would hold that path).

Answer (score 0):

Either

1. Distribute a `settings.xyz.example` file (which they then copy to a new file by removing `.example`, where `settings.xyz` is in `.gitignore`; or
2. Instruct your developers to remove the settings from the index (`git rm --cached filename`) after cloning.

I prefer 1.

Also consider putting in a hook in server side to stop people pushing unwanted files back. I have done this with VS files to stop people unwittingly pushing `.v12.suo` and `.sdf` files which should not be under revision control. Some of these are so huge that you don't want them in the repo at all (`git rm` doesn't remove every trace of them as they remain in old revisions, slowing down cloning).

Comment: Option 2 might work, I'll give that a try. The issue with option 1 is that we have over a hundred small programs, and each one has custom settings. they are all old software in many languages ranging from 5-30 years old that have never been in version control, but I'm trying to make our system more scale able and allow multiple programmers to work on the same projects. Basically it would be a nightmare to keep track of all of those project settings files manually. I'll do some testing and if it works I'll accept this answer.

Comment: You could always have a script that copied all the files locally.

Answer (score 0):

Once a file was added to git index, git status will continue to track changes to that file even if it is in a .gitignore

It sounds like you would like git to ignore changes to the settings template but keep it in the repo. To do that you can use:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged settings.xyz
```

This will keep the file in the the repository, but will ignore any local changes you make.

In order to tell git to start tracking changes again you can use:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged settings.xyz
```